# Selective batch update for a row on Google sheet spreadsheet v4 api

Tags: php, google-sheets-api, google-client

```
$range = "2020!A92:L92";
$valueRange= new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange();
$valueRange->setValues(["values" => ["updatetest1", "updatetest2", "updatetest3", "updatetest4", "updatetest5", "updatetest6", "updatetest7", "updatetest8", "updatetest9", "updatetest10", "updatetest11", "updatetest12"]]); 
$conf = ["valueInputOption" => "RAW"];
$service->spreadsheets_values->update($spreadsheetId, $range, $valueRange, $conf);
```

I have this snippet, but the problem is tha I need to modify B92, F92 and G92 only, so I would need to update those with the values updatetest2, updatetest6 and updatetest7. I could call it three times, but there's probably a better way. I know there's \Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest, but the documentation is pretty parse.

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.html#$responseIncludeGridData

```
$data = [];
array_push(
    $data,
    new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
        'range' => 'B92',
        'values' =>  [["BATCHUPDATE"]]
    ])
);
array_push(
    $data,
    new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
        'range' => 'E92',
        'values' =>  [["BATCHUPDATE"]]
    ])
);
array_push(
    $data,
    new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
        'range' => 'F92',
        'values' =>  [["BATCHUPDATE"]]
    ])
        );
$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest([
    "valueInputOption" => "RAW",
    "data" => $data
]);

$result = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $body);
```

I also tried the following and I am getting:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"valueInputOption\"
: Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"data\": Cann
ot find field.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"valueInputOpti
on\": Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"data\":
Cannot find field.",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The error you are receiving is due to the fact that the `spreadsheets.batchUpdate` request does not expect a field named `valueInputOption`.**

However, since you want to update the values from a sheet, you should use the
`spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate` request and make the following change:

```
$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateValuesRequest([
    "valueInputOption" => "RAW",
    "data" => $data
]);
```

For further use, if needed, you can easily simulate the Sheets API requests by making use of the "Try this API!" from the documentation pages.

#### Reference

- [Class Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateValuesRequest](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateValuesRequest.html);
- [Sheets API spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate).